# how to find the longest word in python?

Tags: python

I a new to python and am stuck on this one exercise. I am supposed to enter a sentence and find the longest word. If there are two or more words that have the same longest length, then it is to return the first word. This is what I have so far:

```
def find_longest_word(word_list):  
    longest_word = ''  
    for word in word_list:    
          print(word, len(word))  


words = input('Please enter a few words')  
word_list = words.split()  
find_longest_word(word_list)
```

But I do not know how to compare the lists and return the first/longest word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't print out the length of each word. Instead, compare the length of the current `word` and the length of `longest_word`. If `word` is longer, you update `longest_word` to `word`. When you have been through all words, the longest world will be stored in `longest_word`.

Then you can print or return it.

```
def find_longest_word(word_list):
    longest_word = ''
    for word in word_list:
        if len(word) > len(longest_word)
            longest_word = word
    print longest_word
```

edit:
levi's answer is much more elegant, this is a solution with a simple for loop, and is somewhat close to the one you tried to make yourself.

Comment: Thank you. My teacher isn't the best (he just says read this and figure it out). Would you be able to explain why there is the longest_word = '' and the if statement? (including the longest_word = word)

Comment: @pythonparadise I can try :). longest_word holds the word that is currently longest, throughout the execution. Upon start it is set to '' which is an empty string. (notice, it is 2x ', and not 1x " that is used). Then in the for loop, for every single word, we compare the length of the current word we are checking, and the longest word found so far (initially with length zero, empty string). If the current word we are checking is longer than the longest previously found, we set the longest_word to word. That way, all future words will be compared to the new longest_word we just found.

Answer (score 25):

Use `max` python built-in function, using as `key` parameter the `len` function. It would iterate over `word_list` applying `len` function and then returning the longest one.

```
def find_longest_word(word_list):  
    longest_word =  max(word_list, key=len)
    return longest_word
```

Comment: I was looking for a one-liner!

Answer (score 0):

Compare each word to the longest one yet, starting with the length of 0. If the word is longer than the longest yet, update the word and the longest_size. Should look similar to this:

```
def find_longest_word(word_list):  
    longest_word = ''  
    longest_size = 0   
for word in word_list:    
    if len(word) > longest_size
        longest_word = word
        longest_size = len(word)      
return longest_word

words = input('Please enter a few words')  
word_list = words.split()  
find_longest_word(word_list)
```